# What datatypes are Facebook's various user data?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

If you go [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile), 
you'll find a list of the public profile data you can access from someone if they use Facebook to login to your site.

- id
- name
- first_name
- last_name
- age_range
- link
- gender
- locale
- picture
- timezone
- updated_time
- verified

But what datatypes do they come in? Without that information, it's tough to do anything with them.

UPDATE:

I tried capturing the data and getting their datatypes by calling the `.class` method on them. `name` yielded "String", but everything else yielded "NilClass".

UPDATE2:

To add to the confusion, `name` actually yields the email address associated with the Facebook account, not the name.

Answer (score 1):

You can see [user object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user). Fields coming from public_profile are of user object.

- id - numeric string
- name - string
- first_name - string
- last_name - string
- age_range - [age-range object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/age-range/)
- link - string
- gender - string
- locale - string
- picture - string
- timezone - float (min: -24) (max: 24)
- updated_time - datetime
- verified - bool

You can use string or long int for id. Because facebook id's are very long and unique for the app.

Comment: Do you know why I might be getting "NilClass" when I try to call `.class` on everything but `name`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# you can use a type of 'dynamic' which works concurrently with 'ExpandoObject'. Very powerful stuff for transforming data types that you are not really 'sure' about.

A sample of code to do so would be as such.

```
dynamic item = faceBookApi.Property;

var type = item.GetType();
```

.Net Framework 4.6.1